# QT - window on top

Tags: c++, qt

'WindowStaysOnTopHint' doesn't work for widget 'ww', why?

```
Dialog w;
widget ww;
ww.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
ww.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
ww.setFixedSize(206,206);
w.show();
ww.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are replacing it with `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`.

If you want both:

```
ww.setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```